# Best practice to manage dependencies between conda and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm developing a Python library, which depends on multiple packages. I'm struggling to find the most straightforward of managing all those dependencies with the following constraints :

- Some of those dependencies are only available as conda packages (technically the source is available but the build process is not something I want to get into)
- Other dependencies are only available via pip
- I need to install my own library in editable or developer mode
- I regularly need to keep the dependencies up-to-date

My current setup for the initial install :

- Create a new conda environment
- Install the conda-only dependencies with `conda install ...`
- Install my library with `pip install -e .`

At this point, some packages were installed and are now managed by conda, others by pip. When I want to update my environment, I need to:

- Update the conda part of the environment with `conda update --all`
- Update the pip part of the environment by hand

My problem is that this is unstable : when I update all conda packages, it ensures the consistency of the packages it manages. However, I can't guarantee that the environment as a whole stays consistent, and I just realized that I was missing some updates because I forgot to check for updates in the pip part of the environment.

What's the best way to do this ? I've thought of :

- Using conda's [pip interoperability feature](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html) : this seems to work, but I've had some dubious results, probably because of my use of *extras_require*
- Since pip can see the conda packages, the initial install is consistent, which means I can simply reinstall everything when I want to update. This works but is not exactly elegant.

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment might be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things I read to get to my current workflow. While it works relatively well for the initial install, it's hard to keep the environment up-to-date when it is managed by both conda and pip.

Comment: Would wrapping the update logic in a script solve your problem?  Example, execute update.sh (update.sh contains all the logic for updating your conda/pip environment)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommendation in [the official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env) for managing a Conda environment that also requires PyPI-sourced or `pip`-installed local packages is to define all dependencies (both Conda and Pip) in a YAML file. Something like:

**env.yaml**

```
name: my_env
channels:
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3.8
 - numpy
 - pip
 - pip:
   - some_pypi_only_pkg
   - -e path/to/a/local/pkg
```

The workflow for updating in such an environment is to update the YAML file (which I would recommend to keep under version control) and then either create a new environment or use

```
conda env update -f env.yaml
```

Personally, I would tend to create new envs, rather than mutate (update) an existing one, and use minimal constraints (i.e., `>=version`) in the YAML. When creating a new env, it should automatically pull the latest consistent packages. Plus, one can keep the previous instances of the env around in case a regression is need during the development lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem like the best way to do things. As a follow-up question : how would you recomment I specify the requirements for development packages (linters, tests, docs, etc.) ?

Comment: @ClémentMasson as far as I understand it, those should be included in the `setup.py` under the appropriate variables, e.g., `tests_require`, similar to any runtime dependencies. Working in Conda gives an opportunity to have Conda pre-install what one needs for a working environment (and avoid having to bother with native dependencies), but `setup.py` is still where all dependencies for the package under development should be declared.

Comment: For now I've found a solution that works for my needs : I specify the test requirements separately in a requirements.txt file (and the setup.py does not contain any). This allows an update with the same command like `conda env update -f env.yml -f test_requirements.txt`. It's probably not the cleanest way of doing things, but it's good enough for what I need. Thanks !